# How can I fetch values from object array using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, fetch

I have this array structure :

```
var $obj = {
        'sections1' : {
            'row1' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            },
            'row2' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            }
        },
        'sections2' : {
            'row3' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            },
            'row4' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            }
        }
    };
```

I want to fetch data from `$obj->section2->row4->key2`. How can I make it using jquery and javascript both.

UPDATE: I want it to print the value in a paragraph or div

```
<p id="array"></p>
```

Comment: `$obj.section2.row4.key2` just replace `->` with dots.

Comment: var Data=$obj.section2.row4.key2;

Comment: @NinaScholz and one more thing I want to print it in a div or para

Comment: Also this is not an array structure, but an java script object!

Comment: should the access be dynamic?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes the access be dynamic

Comment: how do you get the keys?

Comment: @NinaScholz If I enter the key name in input field ( for example : I entered  the row1 so row one data should appear in para

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways. The best suited would be:

1. **Bracket Notation**

   `var prop = object['property_name'];`
2. **Dot Notation**

   `var prop = object.property_name;`

In your case it would be

```js
var obj = {
        'sections1' : {
            'row1' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            },
            'row2' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            }
        },
        'sections2' : {
            'row3' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            },
            'row4' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            }
        }
    };
    
    
    console.log(obj.sections2.row4.key2);//Dot notation
    console.log(obj['sections2']['row4']['key2']);//Bracket notation
    document.getElementById("array").innerHTML=obj.sections2.row4.key2;
```

```html
<p id="array"></p>
```

For more details refer **[MDN Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)**

Hoe it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In javascript use `.` (dot) notation to access values

```js
var obj = {
        'sections1' : {
            'row1' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            },
            'row2' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            }
        },
        'sections2' : {
            'row3' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            },
            'row4' : {
                'key1' : 'input1',
                'key2' : 'inpu2'
            }
        }
    };
    
    
    console.log(obj.sections2.row4.key2);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually it looks quiet simple your requirement
You can use the array notation or (.) dot operator

1) Array notation  `$obj['section2']['row4']['key2'];`

2) Dot operator `$obj.section2.row4.key2;`

Nb: Please use array notation It would be safe in case of unknown keys if the key has a space in it

If you need it iterate through all the keys you can use for in loop